# QtQuick 2.0 get cap height of font

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

In QML (QtQuick 2.0), [FontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html) provides every info about a font's size except its cap height. I really need to find out the cap height of a font for a program (it even provides xHeight but not the cap height!!). Is there a mathematical relation between the x height and cap height? If not, is there any other way of finding the cap height of a font?
Please help! I actually tried searching for all possible solutions but couldn't find anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QFontMetricsF` has `capHeight` method.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetricsf.html#capHeight

May be you can expose from C++ as said below. If that works, `QFontMetricsF` has much better interface which you can use.

The below code is hand written (syntax or compiler errors will be there). But gives you an idea.

```
//EXPOSE THE INFORMATION FROM C++
class fontDetails : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal capHeight READ GetCapHeight CONSTANT)
public:
    
    qreal GetCapHeight() const {
        return QFontMetricsF(<<YOUR FONT>>).capHeight();
    }
};


//SET THE CONTEXT
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    fontDetails fontdetails;
    view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("fontdetails", &fontdetails);
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("<<YOUR QML>>.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And then consume in QML

```
Label {
    text: fontdetails.GetCapHeight()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly, I don't know much about C++ and how to use it with QtQuick, but I'll try :D